# Ajuda - Modificar fórmula ao mudar de radiobutton

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Olá, desenvolvedores!

Preciso de ajuda para meu programa de cálculo do MRU.

Quando eu insiro os dados com o radiobutton metros/segundos ativo, e depois seleciono no radiobutton km/h ele converte os dados corretamente.

Já quando estou em km/h, e clico no radiobutton metros/segundos, ele não está fazendo a conversão...

[image: Design do programa]

```
private void radMetrosSegundos_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblEspacoInicialMedida.Text = "metros";
    lblVelocidadeMedida.Text = "metros/segundos";
    lblTempoMedida.Text = "segundos";
    lblEspacoFinalTipo.Text = "metros";
    /* Essa é a formula mais não funciona quando eu clico em metros /segundos.
    numEspacoInicial.Value = numEspacoInicial.Value * 1000; // KM para metro
    numTempo.Value = numTempo.Value * 3600; // hora para segundos
    numVelocidade.Value = numVelocidade.Value / Convert.ToDecimal(3.6); //segundos para hora
    */
}

private void radKMH_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblEspacoInicialMedida.Text = "Km";
    lblVelocidadeMedida.Text = "Km/h";
    lblTempoMedida.Text = "Horas";
    lblEspacoFinalTipo.Text = "Km";

    //Aqui funciona corretamente
    numEspacoInicial.Value = numEspacoInicial.Value / 1000; // Metro para KM
    numTempo.Value = numTempo.Value / 3600; // segundos para hora
    numVelocidade.Value = numVelocidade.Value * Convert.ToDecimal(3.6); // m/s para km/h
}
```

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: A princípio a função está correta. Verifique se o evento '**radMetrosSegundos_CheckedChanged**' está relacionado ao RadioButton.

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode fazer a verificação de qual radioButton que está checado e dependendo do radioButton faz as alterações e isso tudo apenas em uma void, utilizando um `radioButton.Checked`, esqueça a void `radMetrosSegundos_CheckedChange` deixe ela sem valor, mas não a exclua pois acarretará em erros.

```
private void radKMH_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(radKMH.Checked)
    {
        lblEspacoInicialMedida.Text = "Km";
        lblVelocidadeMedida.Text = "Km/h";
        lblTempoMedida.Text = "Horas";
        lblEspacoFinalTipo.Text = "Km";

        //Aqui funciona corretamente
        numEspacoInicial.Value = numEspacoInicial.Value / 1000; // Metro para KM
        numTempo.Value = numTempo.Value / 3600; // segundos para hora
        numVelocidade.Value = numVelocidade.Value * Convert.ToDecimal(3.6); // m/s para km/h
    }
    else if(radMetrosSegundos.Checked)
    {
        lblEspacoInicialMedida.Text = "metros";
        lblVelocidadeMedida.Text = "metros/segundos";
        lblTempoMedida.Text = "segundos";
        lblEspacoFinalTipo.Text = "metros";
        numEspacoInicial.Value = numEspacoInicial.Value * 1000; // KM para metro
        numTempo.Value = numTempo.Value * 3600; // hora para segundos
        numVelocidade.Value = numVelocidade.Value / Convert.ToDecimal(3.6); //segundos para hora
    }
}
```